# How to use Microsoft Exchange Web Services to retrieve meeting form other contacts in the same domain?

Tags: c#, web-services, calendar, outlook

I would like to retrieve calender items from Outlook 2010. Currently I could only retrieve items from my own calender by following this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn439786%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx). But I want to get meeting from my colleagues calender. I have tried many option so far but nothing is working. Could you please show me how to use these api to get all calender meeting from the same exchange server? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no answer within 2 days. Meanwhile I found a way to access others calender. I want to share my solution so that other can get a helsp:-

```
             ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
             service.Credentials = new WebCredentials();
             Mailbox principle = new Mailbox("usedr@domain.com");
             CalendarFolder calendar2 = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, principle), new PropertySet());
             // Retrieve a collection of appointments by using the calendar view.
             FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments2 = calendar2.FindAppointments(cView2);
```

appointments2 should have all the calender meeting.